# Linear Combinations of Normal Variables and Independence

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reviewing for a final and am unsure how to do one of the review questions re: bivariate normals.

I'm given:

$ Suppose (X,Y) \sim BN(\mu_x=0, \mu_y=0, \sigma_x^2=1, \sigma_y^2=1, \rho=0.6)$

Find c such that 2X + 3Y and 6X +cY are independent.

I'm not quite sure how to approach this as the textbook as no good examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two jointly distributed normal random variables are independent if and only if they are uncorrelated.

Observe that $2X + 3Y$ and $6X + cY$ are linear combinations of jointly normal random variables, hence jointly normal. Also, both have zero mean because $E[X] = E[Y] = 0$ and the expectation operator is linear.

So, you need to find $c$ such that

$E[(2X + 3Y)(6X + cY)] = E[2X+3Y]E[6X+cY] = 0$

Expanding the product, this is equivalent to

$12E[X^2] + (18 + 2c)E[XY] + 3cE[Y^2] = 0$

You should be able to identify $E[X^2]$, $E[Y^2]$, and $E[XY]$ from the information given, and from there it's simple algebra.

Comment: The answer given is c=3/2, but I'm wondering if that is a mistake. Or I'm mistaken on the simpler terms, that E[X^2] and E[Y^2] are equal to 1, and E[XY] here is equal to 0.6.

Comment: Yes, E[X^2] = E[Y^2] = 1, and E[XY] = 0.6. I get c = -38/7, not 3/2. It's easy to see that c cannot be positive, otherwise E[(2X + 3Y)(6X + cY)] must also be positive.